# Error when Installing From LiveCD - unable to find a medium containing a live file system”

Tags: installation, live-cd

I have read the other post but seems like they did not help my problem...So im getting unable to find a medium containing a live file system” error when installing it gets to a certin line in the command line then errors out with that message.  Is there a way or a work around?? I also tried to boot from USB but its booting straight into windows.  I have changed all BIOS settings and changed boot order but still going right to windows the only way it gets some sort of boot is from the LiveCD.  What am I not doing or what am I doing wrong?? Is ther a program I can DL to check and see if the medium is bootable?

PC = HP Omni 120-1134 (All-In-One)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing seems like that your computer doesn't read well your DVD.

when you boot from cd, you have an image that has an icon at the downside at center that is the symbol of a keyboard with a circle in white.

at this moment type any key (I do not remember well)

Afterwards you'll have a menu appearing asking you what you want to do.

Select : check disk for defects.

If it detects some troubles, then, check the integrity of your downloaded iso file (help can be found here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

if everything is alright then burn it again at the slowest speed possible (it highers the burning quality in your medium)

if after this you still have trouble at the "check disk for defects" moment then your burning machine is not burning well : the burner or the brand/model of the dvd disk.

Hopes that helps you.

Best regards.